# How to Join several sed output lines (-e ) to one line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am extracting some data from a logfile using `sed`. My command looks like this:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*\(date\).*/\1/p' -e 's/.*\(details in that entry\).*/\1/p'-e 's/.*\(some more details\).*/\1/p'
```

This always produces 2 or more lines:

```
date
some details
some more details
date(2nd entry) 
some details ( 2nd entry ) 
some more details (2nd entry)
```

and so on...

How can I join the lines coming from the `sed` command set directly to one line like this?

```
date some details some more details
date some details some more details....
```

Comment: Show a sample of log file.

Answer (score 1):

It its every 3rd line:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":RS' file
date some details some more details
date some details some more details
```

or

```
paste -d " " - - - < file
date some details some more details
date some details some more details
```

---

If you can use `date` as a trigger word, you can use this `gnu awk`

```
awk 'NR>1 {$1=RS FS $1;print}' RS="date" file
date some details some more details
date some details some more details
```

(`gnu awk` due to multiple characters in `RS`)